# MYSQL - Find a record depending on row number

Tags: mysql, sql, select, row-number, rownum

Is it possible to get a table record depending on the row number?

For example, I have a table with 40 records and I need to get the 27th record. 
I need some query like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE **ROWNUM** = 27`.

Comment: You can but not with `ROWNUM` that is `Oracle` specific.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `offset`:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
order by ???  -- you need to specify a column or expression here
limit 1 offset 26;
```

Two notes.  There is no such thing as the 27th row of a table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is only an ordering if a column specifies the ordering.  That is the purpose of the `order by`.  Often this might be the primary key for the table.

Second, the offset (unlike most things in SQL) is zero-based.  So an offset of "1" means "skip one record" -- or "start with the second".  Hence an offset of "26".

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, you are looking for simething like this?

```
SELECT *
    FROM some_table t
    where @row = 26;
```

Comment: Yep, I need something like this.